# ERROR! the application has a different value set for key during runtime compared to compile time

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

In my Elixir project, I'm facing the following error and not sure where to set the runtime value to match the compile time one.

Currently the only place I define the key :app_url is in runtime.exs like this, and PHX_HOST is defined as an environment variable. :app_url is then referenced in live.ex like `@app_url Application.compile_env(:myapp, :app_url)` According to the error message, this is the compile time value, and runtime value was not set.

<runtime.exs>

```
config :myapp,
  token_signing_secret: secret_key_base,
  app_url: System.get_env("PHX_HOST"),


ERROR! the application :myapp has a different value set for key :app_url during runtime compared to compile time. Since this application environment entry was marked as compile time, this difference can lead to different behaviour than expected:  

  * Compile time value was set to: "http://localhost:3030"
  * Runtime value was not set

To fix this error, you might:

  * Make the runtime value match the compile time one

  * Recompile your project. If the misconfigured application is a dependency, you may need to run "mix deps.compile myapp --force"

  * Alternatively, you can disable this check. If you are using releases, you can set :validate_compile_env to false in your release configuration. If you are using Mix to start your system, you can pass the --no-validate-compile-env flag


** (ErlangError) Erlang error: "aborting boot"
    (elixir 1.14.1) Config.Provider.boot/2
```

Comment: How do you compile the app and where do you run it? Any docker/virtualization involved?

Comment: Just plain mix compile on my windows laptop. No docker or anything fancy.

Comment: Instead of `@app_url Application.compile_env(:myapp, :app_url)`, can you try fetching the value only at runtime using `Application.fetch_env!(:my_app, :app_url)` and see if that works? AFAICT you're trying to read a config value at compile time (module attribute) but it's only set at runtime.

Comment: I works but I get "Application.fetch_env/2 is discouraged in the module body, use Application.compile_env/3 instead". That's what I was trying to avoid. Thanks.

Comment: It looks weird to me, that you use `Application.compile_env/3` to access a runtime config, but I'd have expected that the error would be the other way around:  `Compile time value was not set` and `Runtime value was set to ...`. Can you maybe share the exact mix commands used to compile and start the application?

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question. I run mix phx.server to start and compile the application, but I doubt that's what you are asking.